# Where should they be buried?

Tags: lateral-thinking

James, the pilot, was flying his plane for a commercial flight. The plane was 
travelling from Chicago to New York. On the plane's course, though, was a storm. To make a long story short - the plane crashed. The problem is that since the plane crashed on the border of Ohio and Pennsylvania, nobody knows where to bury the survivors. Where must they be buried?

Comment: What does the location of death have to do with the location of burial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No where

Because

> They are not dead since they are survivors (alive).

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this one before.

> Nobody gets buried because you don't bury survivors.

Comment: I'm intrigued by what a 'surprised storm' is....